# Relation between BoE rates and fixed Isa rates

Tags: united-kingdom, bonds, isa

I would like to understand the relation between BoE rates and fixed isa rates (if there is one). Is there any kind rule of thumb saying that fixed isa rates should be slightly higher than BoE rates? If so, by how much? To give an example, as of today (mid Dec. 2022) BoE rates are 3.5%, while 2 years fixed isa rates (say for Virgin or Barclays) are around 4.1%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed rate products are mostly driven by the wholesale [interest rate swaps](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/interestrateswap.asp) market. There are lots of entities out there who either want to borrow or lend at a known rate for a fixed period of time. There are others who are happy to to be exposed to the short-term fluctuations of things like the BoE rates. They make agreements with each other by buying or selling swaps where one side will get paid a fixed rate of interest for an agreed period of time, and the other side a so-called "floating" rate.

The floating rate will be something like) [LIBOR](https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/british-pound-sterling/british-pound-sterling.aspx) or [SONIA](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/markets/sonia-benchmark), which roughly reflect the rates at which banks can borrow from each other. These aren't directly tied to the BoE rate but will typically go up and down with it to some extent.

Ultimately, a swap will make money for one party if the average floating rate over the period of the swap is higher than the fixed rate, and for the other party if it's lower. (It's not quite the average floating rate, but it's roughly right and the precise calculation doesn't really matter for this answer.) So the fixed rate on offer for a particular swap should roughly reflect how people think floating rates will vary over time. If "the market" expects that floating rates will fall soon, then the fixed rates on offer might well be lower than the current floating rate.

The banks and building societies offering fixed rate savings products, and fixed rate mortgage products, will use the current fixed rates on offer for interest rate swaps to figure out the rough rate to pay or charge people, allowing for some profit margin for themselves.

So to answer your actual question, you can't work out what fixed rates will be just by looking at today's BoE rate. In practice they will tend to move around to reflect the market's guesses as to how BoE rates will move over the period of the fixed term.

It's not always easy to find swap rates online, but [here's one source as of now](https://www.chathamfinancial.com/technology/european-market-rates) (look at SONIA swaps). It's likely that fixed rate products would go up and down with those swap rates, though I'm not sure what the exact relationship would be.

Comment: Thank you! So, I get from the answer that the relationship is rather involved... I still wonder, do you think that the following situation has any chances to occur at some point in the future: the rate of BoE is 4.5%, while the best 2-years fixed isa rate on the market is 3.5%?  (my gut feeling is that such a situation can't occur, but I might be totally wrong of course)

Comment: @aglearner it absolutely can occur, if the market is expecting rates to drop over that 2 year period. I think I can expand my answer to explain the intuition a bit more clearly, I'll do that later.

Comment: @aglearner now added.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your explanation! I have a last follow up question. Suppose we are in a hypothetical ideal situation, when "everyone knows" (for some reason) that BoE will not change its rate for the next 3 years. Can one expect in such situation that 2 year fixed isa will have a rate higher than the rate of BoE? Or even this can't be assumed?

Comment: @aglearner I'd expect it to be less than the BoE rate, because the BoE rate is what the bank/building society can earn by keeping reserves at the BoE and they would be making a loss if they paid you more than that.